# DB2 to Oracle Conversion For Basic Date Time Column Between Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date, db2, between

What this is doing is selecting all columns from TABLE where a specific date time column is between last Sunday and this coming Saturday, 7 days total (no matter what day of the week you are running the query on)

I would like to have help converting the below statement into Oracle since I found out that it will not work on Oracle.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE_TIME_COLUMN
BETWEEN
current date - ((dayofweek(current date))-1) DAYS
AND
current date + (7-(dayofweek(current date))) DAYS
```

Comment: It's best to [avoid `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially when dealing with date/time/timestamp types.  Use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`) instead.  On the DB2 side, what type is `DATE_TIME_COLUMN`?  (On the oracle side it's for sure date+time, so you're getting the wrong results on occasion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around a bit more I was able to find something that worked for my specific problem with no administrator restrictions for whatever reason:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE_TIME_COLUMN
BETWEEN
    TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, DayOfWeek(Current_Date)*(-1) + 1, Current_Date)
AND
    TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, 7 - DayOfWeek(Current_Date), Current_Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRUNC()` to truncate to the start of the week:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM TABLE
  WHERE DATE_TIME_COLUMN
BETWEEN trunc(sysdate, 'WW')
    and 
        trunc(sysdate + 7, 'WW');
```

`sysdate` is the current system date, `trunc` truncates a data, and `WW` tells it to truncate to the week (rather than day, year, etc.).

Comment: Let me test this on my specific solution then I will get back to approving the answer or not.

Comment: I have been running this in Oracle BI, and the error I got this time was "Function trunc is not defined by administrator" would you have any idea why this would not be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DATE_TIME_COLUMN is - as it should be - of datatype date, I think this gets what you want.

```
where DATE_TIME_COLUMN between
next_day(sysdate,'SUNDAY')-7 and next_day(sysdate,'SATURDAY')
```

You may need to tweak it a bit.  Please follow up studying the official docs on the NEXT_DAY function in the relevant docs at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions106.htm#SQLRF00672

```
The proposed TRUNC does not guarantee you get the date of a particular day of the week:

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='day dd-mon-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate,'WW') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'WW')
---------------------
friday    22-jan-2016

SQL> select trunc(sysdate+7,'WW') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE+7,'WW')
---------------------
friday    29-jan-2016
```

Comment: I will mark this as the correct answer although it seems not to run because Oracle BI says, "Function next_day is not defined by administrator."

Comment: If BI is throwing an error, then we'd need to see your exact code or refer you to a BI forum.  The NEXT_DAY function is internal to the database engine itself and is a fundamental part of Oracle's implementation of the SQL language.  There is nothing to define by "the administrator".

Comment: This is the filter that I am using on Oracle BI: "Activity"."Actual Start Date" BETWEEN next_day(sysdate,'SUNDAY')-7 AND next_day(sysdate,'SATURDAY')

Comment: It appears the reported error message is a BI error.  It is certainly not an Oracle database error.